# How can I configure VMs to suspend or shutdown when the host is rebooted/shutdown with KVM / virt-manager?

Tags: kvm, libvirt, virt-manager

I am running openSUSE Tumbleweed with virt-manager.

I can see an option in the VM details for starting the VM when the host boots up.

[image]

I am trying to find a way to configure what a VM does when the host is shutdown? For example, I want one VM to suspend and another VM to shutdown.